# Single template parameter pack for multiple variadic functions?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Usually we would do something like this to define multiple variadic functions taking the same parameter pack:

```
template<typename ...Pack>
void func1(Pack... params);

template<typename ...Pack>
void func2(Pack... params);

template<typename ...Pack>
void func3(Pack... params);

template<typename ...Pack>
void func4(Pack... params);
```

Is there some way to avoid this redundant repetition? For example, something like:

```
template<typename ...Pack>
{
    void func1(Pack... params);
    void func2(Pack... params);
    void func3(Pack... params);
    void func4(Pack... params);
}
```

Comment: Is this to avoid the typing or do you really need functions which take the same (as in same types) parameter pack?

Comment: do you limit this parameter packs to some subset of types or number of arguments? If not why this is a problem?

Comment: @DanielJour The latter. All the parameters in each of the variadic functions are going to have exactly the same type–just one type.

Comment: @MarekR Sorry, I don't understand your objection.

Comment: Simply I (and probably others) do not understand what is the gain/goal. Is it just to save you a typing when defining this templates? Does it have it impact on how templates are used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre C++20 answer: No, there isn't anything you can do to get a syntax like that.  Best you could do is create a macro that does a lot of the work for you.

C++20: You can use `auto` for the function parameter type which is syntactic sugar for writing out a template like it is for a lambda currently.  That would give you

```
void func1(auto... params);
void func2(auto... params);
void func3(auto... params);
void func4(auto... params);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++17... maybe you can define a single function, with an additional template parameter that is the number of the function, and use `if constexpr` to separate the bodies of the single functions.

I mean something as follows

```
template <int Id, typename ... Pack>
void func (Pack ... params)
 {
   if constexpr ( 1 == id )
    { /* body of func1() */ }
   else if constexpr ( 2 == id )
    { /* body of func2() */ }
   else if constexpr ( 3 == id )
    { /* body of func3() */ }
   // else // etc...
 }
```

Calling `func()` you have to explicit the integer template parameter

```
func<1>("abc"); // equivalent to func1("abc");
```

As observed by Nathan Oliver, when names of functions are important and descriptive (and not a simple enumeration), the use of a integer template parameter gives you a loose of description.

In this case, instead of an `int`, you can add an enum value additional template parameter. With descriptive names for enum values.

Something as

```
enum funcId
 {
   a_complex_and_descriptive_func_id,
   another_complex_func_id,
   a_third_complex_func_id // , etc...
 }     

template <funcId Id, typename ... Pack>
void func (Pack ... params)
 {
   if constexpr ( a_complex_and_descriptive_func_id == id )
    { /* body of first function */ }
   else if constexpr ( another_complex_func_id == id )
    { /* body of second function */ }
   else if constexpr ( a_third_complex_func_id == id )
    { /* body of third function */ }
   // else // etc...
 }
```

and the call become

```
func<a_complex_and_descriptive_func_id>("abc");
```

Comment: Down side to this is now you have to memorize a number for a function, instead of having a nice descriptive function name.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica - Well... if the descriptive function names are `func1`, `func2`, `func3`, I don't think it's worse. If names are really descriptive... instead of an integer, the additional template parameter can be an enum with descriptive values, I suppose.

Comment: I have a feeling func1, func2, ...,  are just place holder names for the OP

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica - I suppose your felling is correct. Answer improved to show the `enum` (verbose and descriptive) alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrap them inside a struct. If you want them independent from any object state you should declare them static.

```
template <typename ...Pack>
struct FunctionHolder
{
    static void func1(Pack... params);

    static void func2(Pack... params);
};
```

[**LIVE SAMPLE**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0c906290be158c2)

Comment: No longer deduced though.